# Counting elements of array stored in hash

Tags: arrays, perl, hash, count

How do I count the elements of an array stored in a hash? When I want to alter the elements I would do it like this:

```
$myObject->{document}->[$i]->{myValue};
```

Somehow I don't get how to get document's count.

I'm new to Perl and all the approaches I've tried work fine for regular arrays, but not for those stored in a hash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply dereference the arrayref:

```
my $count = @{ $myObject->{document} };
```

Comment: As I said—probably pretty easy… Thanks!